# How do I protect my future rights when approaching a publisher with a completed short story?

Tags: publishing, copyright

I have 11 non-fiction stories I am about to shop to magazine publishers. How do I protect my second and third . . . etc. publishing rights in my negotiations with first time publishers? How do I protect my rights to put the stories together in book form?

Answer (score 5):

Well, usually magazines buy only first publishing rights + limited anthology rights. So you don't have to protect anything because that's all they want. If you're finding magazines that say they want more, don't submit to them, they aren't doing the industry standard and there's better places to submit.